# What is the purpose of using the transpose to find the basis for the span?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The question from my test book asks to find the basis for the span of the set:
$$\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}3\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1\\-3\\-3\end{pmatrix}\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3
$$

The solution shows that the professor transposed the matrix and then the row reduced to find the 2 bases $\left\langle\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\-5\\-4\end{pmatrix} \right\rangle
$. However, I understand that if I just row reduced without transposing, I would be finding the basis for the row space. Can someone please explain why I have to write the vectors as rows (i.e., transpose) to find the basis for the span?

Thanks!

Comment: You certainly do not have to. Do you know how to find a basis for the *column space* of $A$ by row reducing $A$?

Comment: Prof. @TedShifrin I understand that the steps would be to transpose columns to rows and then use Gauss's method to find the basis for the span of the rows. I would then transpose them back to columns. But couldn't I just do row reduction without transposing to begin with?

Comment: English technicality: The solution did not find two bases, it found one basis with two vectors.

Comment: Performing row operations preserves the row space but not the column space, while performing column operations preserves the column space but not the row space. You should not expect the output of row operations to be columns which span the original column space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without transposing, you can use the row echelon form to recover a basis of the column space. It has the advantage of being expressed as a subset of the original vectors. See, for example, lectures 37 and 38 of [my course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd). The punchline is this: Take the columns of the original matrix in which you find pivots in the row echelon form.